# Flexible functions R

Tags: r, statistics, user-defined-functions

I have written some code to create my own descriptive statistics table since the default `summary` doesn't do what I want.

Now what I would like is to create a flexible / dynamic function that does this with varying number of variables.

My code looks like this:

```
N <- c( length(data1), length(data2), length(data3) ) 
mean<- c( mean(data1), mean(data2), mean(data3) )
sd <- c( sd(data1), sd(data2), sd(data3) )
min <- c( min(data1), min(data2), min(data3) )
max <- c( max(data1), max(data2), max(data3) )
print(q) <- data.frame(N, mean, sd, min, max)
```

So instead of editing this if i want descriptive of something else than 3 variables I would like a function that did something like this;

```
descriptive <- function(data1, ...) {
  N <- c( length(data1), length(...) ) 
  mean<- c( mean(data1), mean(...) )
  sd <- c( sd(data1), sd(...) )
  min <- c( min(data1), min(...) )
  max <- c( max(data1), max(...) )
  q <- data.frame(N, mean, sd, min, max)
  print(q)
}
```

I tried the above and hoped it would work, but it only works with two variables. As you might see, I am new to R. I have tried to search for a solution, but I've not been able to find one. But if R is as good as "they" say, I think something like this should be possible.

There's probably a function that already does this, but I would like to be able to do it my self. (: Hope someone can help me!

EDIT!!

Thank you all for your answers, they all seem to work. This shows there are multiple answers to the same question in R. I don't know if you get points for the accepted answer and if this is important, but I choose Arun answers since it comes closed to my aim of creating a descriptive table that is "good looking" and flexible.

If anyone in the future is interested I've add this to Arun answer that makes it fit my purpose perfect;

```
data <- list(var1, var2 ...)
names <- c"name1", "name2", "...")
descriptive(data)
```

This solution also seems to have the benefit of variables of different lengths vs data frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a `list` as input to your function argument and then use `sapply` on each to get the statistic for each data.

```
descriptive <- function(ll) {
    N <- sapply(ll, length)
    mean <- sapply(ll, mean)
    sd <- sapply(ll, sd)
    min <- sapply(ll, min)
    max <- sapply(ll, max)
    print(out <- data.frame(N, mean, sd, min, max))
}

descriptive(list(1:5, 6:10))

  N mean       sd min max
1 5    3 1.581139   1   5
2 5    8 1.581139   6  10
```

Note: This'll work even if your input is a `data.frame` and you require statistics on all columns of your data.frame (as it's internally a list).

```
descriptive(data.frame(1:5, 6:10))
      N mean       sd min max
X1.5  5    3 1.581139   1   5
X6.10 5    8 1.581139   6  10
```

Comment: Or use `function(...) ll <- list(...)`

Answer (score 4):

This would be a good opportunity to learn the `apply` family of functions, so that you can specify your intended output as a function and then `apply` that to a dataframe.

```
mydf <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100)) # example data

descriptive <- function(x)
   c(length=length(x), mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x), min=min(x), max=max(x))

sapply(mydf, descriptive) # apply `descriptive` to the df
```

The output:

```
                   x             y             z
length  1.000000e+03 1000.00000000 1000.00000000
mean    3.846765e-03   -0.02009427    0.02001385
sd      9.818488e-01    0.97662850    1.01543571
min    -2.905149e+00   -3.25904432   -3.33017918
max     3.235993e+00    2.86892044    3.13183601
```

One caution with this is that unless you develop a more sophisticated `descriptive` function, it won't be able to handle `NA` values in your data and will cause you problems for variables of different classes in the dataframe (e.g., the mean of a character vector is `NA`).

This is also more efficient than building a function that internally applies to a list of vectors (as Arun suggests) and **plyr** (from Baptiste: `ldply(mydf, each(length, mean, sd, min, max))`):

```
mydf <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1e5),y=rnorm(1e5),z=rnorm(1e5))
microbenchmark(sapply(mydf,thomas), arun(mydf), baptiste(mydf))

Unit: milliseconds
                 expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 sapply(mydf, thomas)  5.693252  6.039458  7.139658  7.953309 43.32675   100
           arun(mydf) 15.805778 18.522889 19.417559 22.016125 57.93630   100
       baptiste(mydf) 10.995073 11.597998 12.666252 13.861521 47.85533   100
```

Comment: `apply` and data frames don't go well together, since it turns its argument into a matrix. Use `lapply` instead.

Comment: with plyr, `ldply(mydf, each(length, mean, sd, min, max))`

Comment: @baptiste I like that syntax, it's very succinct.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to be able to use `...`:

```
test <- list( seq(10), seq(5) )

descriptiveRow <- function(x) {
  res <- c(length(x), mean(x), sd(x), min(x), max(x))
  names(res) <- c("N","Mean","SD","Min","Max")
  res
}

descriptive <- function( ... ) {
  l <- list(...)
  res <- as.data.frame( lapply( l, descriptiveRow ) )
  colnames(res) <- seq(ncol(res))
  res
}

descriptive(test[[1]], test[[2]])

> descriptive(test[[1]], test[[2]])
            1        2
N    10.00000 5.000000
Mean  5.50000 3.000000
SD    3.02765 1.581139
Min   1.00000 1.000000
Max  10.00000 5.000000
```